# loop asking for usename and password

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Published sharepoint site over internet

If i tried to browse the site inside the company network,  it does not accept credential but It is working witout any issue with pc that not joined to the company domain

I added the site url in trusted site,  compatabilty view. ..etc, in IE And chrome, I thought the issue related to policy! !

I checked Response header that give 401 unauthorized with the loop back issue

Comment: Machine or network related issue. Not a sharepoint related issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  I checked multiple machine with the same result,  and network is already reached to the site! The issue with any machine joined to domain, I want to inform the client you have issue in. ....... With proff,  please help!

Comment: check with some firewall settings some port not open..its really a network related issue.